# Hyper-V shutdown Merge is taking a very long time

Tags: hyper-v

When I right click on a VM in Hyper-V Manager and click 'Shut down' it will usually say "Merge in Progress" and take a very long time to complete. During that time RAM and Disk 0 usage in Task Manager will be 100% and the host computer becomes completely unusable for that duration. The longer the Hyper-V stays awake before the shutdown the longer will the Merge take (if the VM was up for a minute the merge will take ~15 minutes, if the VM was up for a couple of days or a week the merge will take 1-2 hours).

My coworkers that use Hyper-V don't seem to have this issue. My understanding is that this has to do with Checkpoints but I don't think I should disable them since AFAIK that would make the data on the VM more volatile and in case of a crash I might lose some of my work.

Can you guys comment on if this is normal and if I can do anything to prevent those long merges? What I usually do is try to remember to shut down the VM daily but if I forget to do that on a Friday I really pay the price on the following Monday when I happen to need a reboot.

**Update**:
I do have an SSD, the processor is i7 4th gen at 3.60GHz, 32GB of RAM

Comment: Ask your coworkers whether they have Checkpoints enabled. I don't, because I don't run production workloads.

Comment: It sounds like a case for SSD and potentially more system memory.  It's entirely possible the reason it's slow is due to the lack of a SSD (if that is the case) and the processor you have.